# How can I test the first character on each line of a listing?

Tags: listings, hooks

The listings package defines a hook called `EveryLine` to allow users to execute TeX code at the beginning of each line of a listing; the following is taken directly from the `listings` source code ([`listings.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx)):

> ```
> \hookname{EveryLine}
>
> Executed at the beginning of each \emph{output} line, i.e.~more than
> once for broken lines. This hook must not change the horizontal or
> vertical position.
> ```

The code below is my attempt at using this hook to test whether the first character of each line is `f` and insert `YES` before it in that case. However, as  you can see below, I'm not getting the expected output.

At first, I thought if might be a grouping problem: the code inserted at the `EveryLine` might be buried inside a group and, as a result, my test could not access the first token on the line, because that token lies outside the group in question. However, a quick test (consisting in locally incrementing a TeX register) shows that it's not the case.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.c}
foo
bar
frivolous
thing
discourse
fragile
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{\@ddedToEveryline}
\def\detectF#1{\ifx f#1 YES#1\fi}
\newcount\mycount
\def\advandprintCount{\advance\mycount by \@ne\the\mycount}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\let\@ddedToEveryline\detectF
\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{sample.c}

\let\@ddedToEveryline\advandprintCount
\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{sample.c}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure this is an answer, but 'this won't work'. If you insert a `\showtokens` into th ehook, you'll find that `#1` is not the start of the line of output but a load of `listings` code: you therefore never see the letter you are after.

Comment: @JosephWright How do you insert `showtokens` into the hook? `\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{\showtokens}
\makeatother` returns an error.

Comment: `\def\detectF#1{\showtokens{#1}\ifx f#1 YES#1\fi}}` then `\def\detectF#1{\showtokens\expandafter{#1}\ifx f#1 YES#1\fi}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.c}
foo
bar
frivolous
thing
discourse
fragile
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{\@ddedToEveryline}

\def\@splitfirstchar#1#2\@nil{\gdef\@detectF{#1}}
\def\splitfirstchar#1{\@splitfirstchar#1\@nil} 
\def\@detectF{%
%  -\the\lst@token-
  \expandafter\splitfirstchar\expandafter{\the\lst@token}%
  \def\@tempa{f}%
%  -\@detectF-
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\@detectF}{\@tempa}=\z@
     YES
  \else
     NO
  \fi%
}
\newcount\mycount
\def\advandprintCount{\advance\mycount by \@ne\the\mycount}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\let\@ddedToEveryline\@detectF
\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{sample.c}

\let\@ddedToEveryline\advandprintCount
\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{sample.c}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: The output looks promising! Your code returned an error, so I took the liberty to edit it. Let me experiment with it a bit more before I give you the checkmark, but your solution looks like what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks again. At some stage, I should really allocate some time to read the `listings` source code from beginning to end.

Comment: Marco, here is a follow-up question (assuming it's not too involved): how could I also peek at the second token on the line?

Comment: @Jubobs: You can use: `\def\@splitfirstchar#1#2#3\@nil{\gdef\@detectFirst{#1}\gdef\@detectSecond{#2}}`